# Copy extent from one map to another in QGIS Layout

Tags: qgis, extents, layouts

I'm trying to create a print layout with four maps that each show the same extent, but that each have different layers on top for examples:

Map 1 has satellite imagery for Zone B
Map 2 has contours for Zone B
Map 3 has a polygon layer showing water for Zone B
Map 3 has a polygon layer showing roads for Zone B

I want all four maps to show the exact same extent and scale.

I know I could just copy/paste the maps, but I've got to layouts for 16 zones and I've set myself up a nice template so copy/pasting would mess that up.

I know there is a 'match extent' tool or similar in ArcGIS Pro, I just can't see it in QGIS...is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered creating an atlas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

###### Synchronising the extents

Perhaps the simplest way to synchronise the extents, that I am aware of, is making Maps 2 and 3 overviews of Map 1 (without a visible extent indicator).

[image]

Ensure that the **Center on overview** checkbox is checked.

You can either change the overview "Frame style" to be transparent, or check off the **Draw "Overview 1" overview"** checkbox. However, this checkbox must be checked initially to allow configuring the overview. Once it is configured you can check it off.

###### Synchronising the scale

To synchronise the scale, you can use an expression as a data-defined override in Maps 2 and 3 that captures the scale of Map 1, like so:

Click the data-defined override button next to "Map Scale" and choose *Edit*.

[image]

Enter the following expression (replacing 'Map 1' with the name of your own "master" map if it is different):

```
item_variables('Map 1')['map_scale']
```

This will ensure that the scale of Maps 2 and 3 match Map 1.

###### Result

[image]

---

###### Alternative to using Overviews

It is a bit fiddly, but you can also use an expression to synchronise the extents, but you need to apply an expression for "X min", "Y min", "X max", "Y max" separately for Maps 2 and 3.

Here I show only the expression for "X min" but the rest should be self-explanatory:

```
x_min( item_variables('Map 1')['map_extent'] )
```

Apply it here, and repeat for the rest, be sure to change `x_min` for `y_min`, `x_max`, `y_max`.

[image]

Comment: Cool solution, +1!

Comment: Nice one, indeed!